# iPhone warning when installing build on device

Tags: iphone, device

hii i am new to user....
when i am installing the build in the device i am getting the warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/sudharastogi/Documents/Kapil/iPhone Project Docs/Buy Me/build/Debug-iphoneos"/Buy Me.app/Buy Me" (file not found).......

Can you please help me out why this warning is coming...... as it causes problem later after some time using the app. The app gets hanged or the NIB named files not found error started coming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related. The "symbols", most likely, means debug symbols. NIB not found errors should not happen because of lack of those.

To alleviate, try one of the following:

- build the release configuration and install that on the device
- connect the device to the computer where you're developing, choose "Device" as the target platform and run

The first eliminates the need for debug symbols; the second should install them along with the app package.